# JavaFX Media - pause(); method makes MediaPlayer fast-forward?

Tags: java, javafx, media, pause

the `pause()` method of `MediaPlayer` makes the `Media` "seek" a bit.
It's really annoying but I didn't find out where the problem is.

```
    private void playPauseClicked() 
    {     
        Status currentStatus = player.getStatus();
        if(currentStatus == Status.PLAYING)
        {
            Duration d1 = player.getCurrentTime(); //To measure the difference
            player.pause();
            Duration d2 = player.getCurrentTime();
            VIDEO_PAUSED = true;
        }
        else if(currentStatus == Status.PAUSED || currentStatus == Status.STOPPED)
        {
            player.play();
            VIDEO_PAUSED = false;
        }
    }
```

The result is not clear, it's something about 200-400ms difference between spot d1 and d2.

Of course I tried to seek my player back to d1 after pausing the media, didn't work, same result after resuming the media.

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the [pause](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#pause%28%29) method does not stop the playing instantly (when `pause` is called, the media still plays and stops exactly at the moment when the [statusProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#statusProperty) changes):

> Pauses the player. **Once the player is actually paused the status will
>   be set to MediaPlayer.Status.PAUSED.**

Therefore the measurements are not really relevant, because when you get the current time `Duration d1 = player.getCurrentTime();` before the pause, the playing is not actually paused and also when you get the current time after the call of `pause` with `Duration d2 = player.getCurrentTime();` is not correct, as `pause` has been executed asynchronously therefore there is no garantie that at `d2` the video stopped to play:

> The operation of a MediaPlayer is inherently asynchronous.

What you could do to get the correct time when the playing is stopped is to observe the changes of the status of the `MediaPlayer` using e.g. [setOnPaused](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPaused%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

**Example:**

```
private void playPauseClicked() {
    Status currentStatus = player.getStatus();

    if(currentStatus == Status.PLAYING)
        player.pause();
    else if(currentStatus == Status.PAUSED || currentStatus == Status.STOPPED) {
        System.out.println("Player will start at: " + player.getCurrentTime());
        player.play();
    }
}

player.setOnPaused(() -> System.out.println("Paused at: " + player.getCurrentTime()));
```

*Sample output:*

```
Paused at: 1071.0203000000001 ms
Player will start at: 1071.0203000000001 ms
Paused at: 2716.7345 ms
Player will start at: 2716.7345 ms
```

**Note:** However it is not needed to set the time of the `MediaPlayer` in the case if you just want to stop and play, but if you want to you can use [seek](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#seek%28javafx.util.Duration%29) method.

Comment: Wow, awesome! I watched a lot of videos and been reading to find out how to do this...
Thanks a lot! Appreciate your help.